# Flux of vector field $F(x,y,z) = (\frac{1}{6}x^2yz,\frac{1}{4}xy^2z,\frac{1}{12}xyz^2)$ through cube

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I'm trying to calculate the flux of the vector field $F(x,y,z) = (\frac{1}{6}x^2yz,\frac{1}{4}xy^2z,\frac{1}{12}xyz^2)$ through the surface:
$$ \Omega = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : 0 \leq x,y,z \leq 2\}$$
$\Omega$ is of course the cube. I tried using the divergence theorem but I did not get anywhere. I also tried to use some form of parametrization but I did not succeed.

Any hints?

Comment: Why didn't you get anywhere with the divergence theorem? You have $\text{div}\,F=xyz$; integrating over your cube gives $8$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic would you like to post your comment as an answer so you receive the credit you deserve?

Comment: @BenjaminMoss: this question is too low-level for the credit to matter, and the question isn't useful for other readers. If the OP made a careless error, the question should just be deleted. If there is a substantive error or deeper question, the question should be revised. As is, the question is of absolutely zero interest to a general audience. So I left a comment, not an answer, because I hope the question isn't kept permanently on the site in this form.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I understand. May I have your permission to answer the question, or should we both just stand firm and allow the OP to register your comment and work through the problem themselves?

Comment: @BenjaminMoss: you don't need my permission to do anything.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Well it was your work that led to the problem being trivial, so I did not want to plagiarize.

Comment: You recieved two answers to your question. Is any of them what you were looking for? If so, consider accepting it, and also upvote any answer that was usefull to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

\begin{align*}
\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2}\text{div}\,F} &=\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2}}\bigg[\frac{2}{6}+\frac{3}{6}+\frac{1}{6}\bigg]xyz\,dx\,dy\,dz \\
&= \displaystyle{\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2}}xyz\,dx\,dy\,dz \\
&=\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2}\bigg[\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\bigg|^{2}_{0}\bigg]\,yz\,dy\,dz\\
&=\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2}}2yz\,dy\,dz.
\end{align*}
We notice that since we have the same bounds and same variables, each individual integral will evaluate to $2$ and we will be left with $8$ as our final answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need a parametrization. Hint: your limits of integration for the triple integral you need are all from 0 to 2.